# How to get only distinct customers for specific records?

Tags: sql

Ex :-

```
     Customer_ID    Transaction_type
         111           Payroll
         111           Saving
         112           payroll
         113           Online 
         113           Payroll
         114           Payroll
```

1) I want Customer_Id 112 and 114 who has only payroll account.
2) I want customers 111 and 113 who has other transaction type with payroll separately.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit short, can you explain a bit further what you really need? Edit your question to include table structure, sample data, expected output and your current attempt and why it isn't working. Also please tag the dbms you are using (mysql, sql server, oracle, etc.)

Comment: Please [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48703033/edit) your DBMS (sql-serveur, oracle, etc...) they have not the same syntax and Sql is a standard.

Comment: So you want all customers - 111, 112, 113 and 114. Shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still not much clear but the simple `GROUP BY` Clause is enough for the above

Who has only one payroll account

```
select Customer_ID 
from table
group by Customer_ID
having count(Transaction_type) = 1 and 
sum(case when Transaction_type = 'payroll' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Who has other transaction type with payroll separate

```
select Customer_ID 
from table
group by Customer_ID
having count(Transaction_type) > 1 and 
sum(case when Transaction_type = 'payroll' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to query customers having only one transaction type

```
SELECT Customer_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Customer_ID    
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Same way to distinctly query the customers having different transaction type

```
 SELECT Customer_ID, COUNT(*)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY Customer_ID    
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

PS: This can be refined based on your question